# Face Detection ios7 Coordinates Scaling Issue

Tags: ios, image, uiimageview, scale, face-detection

I am using the Face Detection API and would like to know how to convert coordinates from large high resolution images to smaller images displayed on an UIImageView. So far, I have inverted the co-ordinate system of my image and container view so that it matches the Core Image coordinate system and I have also calculated the ratio of heights between my high resolution image and the dimensions of my image view, but the coordinates that I am getting are not accurate at all. I am assuming I cannot convert the points from the large image to the small image as easily as I thought. Can anyone please point out my mistake(s)?

```
[self.shownImageViewer setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,-1)];
[self.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,-1)];

//240 x 320
self.shownImageViewer.image = self.imageToShow;

yscale = 320/self.imageToShow.size.height;
xscale = 240/self.imageToShow.size.width;
height = 320;

CIImage *image = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:[self.imageToShow CGImage]];

CIContext *faceDetectionContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CIDetector *faceDetector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:faceDetectionContext options:@{CIDetectorAccuracy:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh}];

NSArray * features = [faceDetector featuresInImage:image options:@{CIDetectorImageOrientation:[NSNumber numberWithInt:6]}];

for(CIFaceFeature *feature in features)
{
    if(feature.hasLeftEyePosition)
        self.leftEye = feature.leftEyePosition;
    if(feature.hasRightEyePosition)
        self.rightEye = feature.rightEyePosition;
    if(feature.hasMouthPosition)
        self.mouth = feature.mouthPosition;
}

NSLog(@"%g and %g",xscale*self.rightEye.x, yscale*self.rightEye.y);
NSLog(@"%g and %g",yscale*self.leftEye.x, yscale*self.leftEye.y);
NSLog(@"%g",height);
self.rightEyeMarker.center = CGPointMake(xscale*self.rightEye.x,yscale*self.rightEye.y);
self.leftEyeMarker.center = CGPointMake(xscale*self.leftEye.x,yscale*self.leftEye.y);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start by removing the transform from your image view.  Just have the image view display the image in the orientation its in already.  This will make the calculations a lot easier.

Now the `CIFaceFeature` outputs its features in image coordinates.  But your imageView might be smaller or bigger.  So first, keep it simple and setting the imageView's content mode to top left.

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTopLeft;
```

Now you dont have to scale the coordinates at all.

When you are happy with that set the contentMode to something more sensible like aspect fit.

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Now you need to scale the x and the y co-ordinates by multiplying each co-ordinate by the aspect fit ratio.

```
 CGFloat xRatio = imageView.frame.size.width / image.size.width;
 CGFloat yRatio = imageView.frame.size.height / image.size.height;
 CGFloat aspectFitRatio = MIN(xRatio, yRatio);
```

Lastly you want to add the rotation back in. Try to avoid this if possible, e.g. fix you images so they are upright to begin with.